# Import Houdini particles simulation and display it as icosphere

Tags: particles, import

I imported a foam simulation from Houdini to Blender. But I don't know how to display the particles as object.

The import is an `.abc` archive.

It is a large sim with 900,000 particles.

Comment: I am not familiar with an abc archive or Houdini, but 900,000… um, assuming the problem is not that your computer is now on fire, what does it import as, if not an object? Does the scene show no change? Is there an error in the bottom right? Can you add screenshots of the 3D viewport and Outliner editors?

Comment: I dont get any error, because I imported it like a Secuence, not a single file. Its get imported like points. I tried converting this points in instaces with geometry nodes, but in the high frames with lots of "particles" are over 70 millions of objects (I change the instaced object to a cube for optimization). The houdini render can handle that easely because its dosent work with objects at all, they are particles. I dont know if there is any way of importing that particle sistem instead of points to instaces.

Comment: “Its get imported like points?” as in, it imports into an object that is purely floating vertices? Or does it import to some data block that is not an object? What do you mean you imported it like a sequence instead of a single file? That’s an image thing. Please add screenshots. Also, the level of English you are at right now seems to be just barely enough to productively communicate about this problem; consider using a translator instead.

Comment: Im sorry about my English level. When I say it's imported as a sequence, I mean that blender (so as not to break, I imagine), allows you to import .abc files as sequence files. And it doesn't just upload a 10GB file, it just uploads a smaller file of just the currently selected frame. And blender converts the import to Verts.

Comment: Oh… I was wrong. ABC files are individual frames of an animation, but are not graphical images.

Comment: I think I've found a pretty optimal way to do it. But anyway, thanks for being patient with me. And if you think of a better way to do it, I'll be happy to try it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the import.
[image: Import_IMG]

And this blender.
[image: Blender]

---

I think I have found a way to display these "particles".

The best way I have found so far has been with geometry nodes. We simply instantiate the points as cubes (I still don't know if it is the least resource consuming geometric shape in blender), then we use realize instances. In this way it is possible to work with these amounts of particles, but you have to be careful with the amount of polygons generated. Because it scales very fast.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the solution I ended up with, but surely there are more optimal ways to do it without consuming so many resources.
If you think of any other way, put it so I can try it.